# Slack API dealing with two API's

Tags: node.js, api, bots, slack-api

I am trying to call a function after getting the response from API calls. Like this

```
function saveScore(bot,result,message){
    getFirstScore(bot,result).then(function(fscore){   //API -1
        if(fscore){
            getSecondScore(bot,result,null).then(function(sscore){  //API -2
                if(fscore && sscore){
                    var finalScores = "First score is " + fscore + " :innocent:" + "\n Second score is "+ sscore +" :blush: ";
                    var remindAttachment = util.reminderAttachment("",finalScores);
                    listAllScores(bot,message,remindAttachment);
                }
            },function(error){
                console.log('sscore error: ' + error);
            });
        }
    },function(error){
        console.log('fscore error: ' + error);
    });
}

function listAllScores(bot,message,remindAttachment){
    sendInstructions = function(response, convo){
        convo.say(remindAttachment);
        convo.say("Take it to the next level:");
        convo.next();
        setTimeout(function(){         
         listScores(bot,message);
        },2000);
    }                           
    bot.startPrivateConversation(message, sendInstructions);
}
```

Here, I want to call **listScores(bot,message);** function after **convo.say(remindAttachment);**. But right now it is loading **listScores(bot,message);** first. So, I am setting timeout(not a good approach) for **listScores(bot,message);** to load after sometime.

Is there any better way to call **listScores(bot,message);** function after  **convo.say(remindAttachment);**

**Edit**

```
function listAllScores(bot,message,remindAttachment){
    sendInstructions = function(response, convo){
        convo.say(remindAttachment, function(error){
            console.log("error ::::::::::::::::::::",error);
            if(error!=null) { 
                listScores(bot,message); 
            }
        });
    }                           
    bot.startPrivateConversation(message, sendInstructions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify this convo.say() function to have callback as a function parameter and then inside that callback call "listScores(bot,message)" function. 
like this
convo.say(remindAttachment, function(error) {
  if(error!=null) {
    listScores(bot,message)
}
})

Comment: thanks for reply. Tried using callback but that callback function is not getting called.

Comment: can u give me the snippet of the convo.say function?